# How to run IPython console that uses the core of the running Jupyter Notebook in DataSpell IDE?

Tags: python, ide, jupyter, jupyter-lab, dataspell

I want to run an IPython console in DataSpell IDE that uses the core of the running Jupyter Notebook.

I want to have notebook cells to work with, and an IPython console where I can test some things. In the same way as in JupyterLab or Spyder. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

When a Jupyter server is running in DataSpell, you can open the Jupyter console using **Help | Find Action**, and type in **Open Jupyter Console**. This console will be using the same kernel as your notebook.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful feature. Is it possible to change the default fontsize for the console? Also is it possible to enable auto completion?